# Re-Evaluating Routine: Likely A/B --> A/B/C split

Tags: routine

Height/weight/age: 6'1 (185 cm) /200 lbs (90kg) / mid 20s (Have been working out seriously for at least 7 years, but martial arts/gymnastics, etc all my life, though my numbers are crap)

I think I need to add another day to my split - A/B/C, instead of A/B. Right now my routine looks like this (feel free to skim or skip to last part of post):

Both A and B:

20 minute warm up - stuff like arm and neck circles, etc
3 miles run @ 9 min/miles

A (not necessarily in order):

3 x 18 push ups
3 x 18 hanging knee raises (for abs, legs bent)
4 x 15 second L-seat holds
3 x 6 bench @ 185 lbs
5 x 8 barbell row @ 145 lbs
3 x 10 "stationary" lunges (no step forward)

B:

5 x 6 pull ups/chin ups
5 x 6 OHP @ 135 lbs
3 x 40 "reverse toe raises" (lean on wall, raise toes, for shins, opposite of calf raises)
3 x 18 calf raises @ 30 lbs
4 bodyweight exercises for back/glutes that I use to make up for deadlifts, high reps or high time static holds + planks (e.g. supermans, alternating supermans, etc)
3 x 8 single leg extension @ 50 lbs (on leg extension machine)
3 x 8 single leg flexion @ 50 lbs (also on machine)

Stuff I am not doing but absolutely have to:
Glute bridges / other stuff for glutes/hams - I have lordosis, but I am positive it's due to hip flexor inflexibility rather than abdominal weakness (at least that's my guess since I can hold L-seats and such fine), but maybe I need to add more ab work, just always seemed...vain, but then I realized all the leg raise stuff I have been doing is mainly flexors, not abs.

The problem: I now workout every 3-4 days, so AxxxBxxxA or AxxBxxA. More commonly, the former. To me, that seems like a ridiculously long time between workouts. I used to do AxBxA. So, it seems that I need to split more so I am back to AxBxC or AxxBxxC. Running isn't holding me back btw, I just don't recover fast enough from the lifting.

Anyway, looking for advice on how to split this up into A/B/C and any glaring deficiencies in my program. I won't squat or deadlift until I get the lordosis **** fixed.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

A common 3-day split is PPL (Push, Pull, Legs).

Push - Presses (Bench, OHP, etc...)
Pull - Rows (Pull ups, Cable rows, BB rows, etc...) & Flys (DB flys, Cable flys)
Legs - Leg exercises

Based on the exercises you have listed, this is what it might look like:

#### Push

Push ups
Bench Press
Dips
OHP
Tricep extentions

#### Pull

Barbell row
Deadlift (or your deadlift substitutes)
Pull ups
Cable row
Curls
L-sits

#### Legs

Squats
Leg Curls
Calf Raises
Lunges
Leg Flexions

I would personally add a warm-up jog before, and a higher paced run to end the workout.

Note: this can be scaled up in frequency per week, just repeat the order.